# How to pass the value of a list or an array from code behind to jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Let's say I want to scan my local drive or a particular local folder for all images. What I want to do is get all the location of all the images and store it in a list/array then after that JQuery will going to refer to the list/array for a slideshow.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this in your .aspx should do the trick. You can then reference imageList from your included Javascript. You need to include a reference to System.Web.Extensions.dll for [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

**.aspx Page:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var imageList = <%=new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MyImages\", "*.png")) %>
    for(var i in imageList) {
        console.log(imageList[i]);
    }
</script>
...
</html>
```

Comment: This is interesting. I want to implement this in my project however I'm not that good at combining asp.net to javascript. If you can provide a simple example how to apply this that would help me a lot.

Comment: I wish I have at least 15 reputation so that I can vote for your answer.